# $B$-fields where field lines are parallel have zero magnetic tension?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, vector-fields

The magnetic tension of a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is given by $(\vec{B} \cdot \nabla )\vec{B}$.

It is easy to see that a uniform field has zero magnetic tension.

My textbook says the magnetic tension is zero for a field where all the field lines are parallel, which I guess means $\vec{B}(\vec{r})=B(\vec{r})\vec{u}$ for some constant vector $\vec{u}$.

However, calculating $(\vec{B} \cdot \nabla )\vec{B}$ for such a field does not give zero!?!

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parallel field lines, the only way the field strength can vary is in the direction perpendicular to the field. This means the magnetic tension is zero.

The magnetic tension is given by (for your example of $\vec{B}=B\vec{u}$)
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(\vec{B}\cdot \nabla)\vec{B} &=& (B \vec{u}\cdot \nabla)B\vec{u} \nonumber \\
& = & B \vec{u}\cdot (B(\nabla \vec{u}) + (\nabla B) \vec{u})\nonumber \\
& = &  B \vec{u}\cdot (\nabla B)\vec{u} \nonumber\\
& = &  B (\vec{u} \cdot \nabla B)\vec{u} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}$$
But
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = \vec{u}\cdot \nabla B =0$$
so the magnetic tension is also zero.

A more straightforward example: Assume Cartesian coordinates and imagine a B-field confined to the $xy$ plane, with $B_y=0$. This defines a field with parallel field lines, but the field strength could vary with $y$ (and still be divergence-free).

The magnetic tension is then given by
$$B_x \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial x} + B_y \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial y} = 0$$
because  $\vec{B} \neq f(x)$ and $B_y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A magentic field everywhere  satisfies $\nabla\cdot {\bf B}=0$, so a magnetic field with  parallel field lines has $({\bf B}\cdot \nabla){\bf B}=0$. To see that this is so, suppose that only the $z$ component of the field is non zero. Then $0=\nabla\cdot {\bf B}=\partial_z B_z$, so $B_z$ is indepenedent of $z$,  but then $({\bf B}\cdot \nabla){\bf B}=0$ as it is the derivative of ${\bf B}$ in the $z$ direction.

Comment: no you have misunderstood the mathematical notation of the operator introduced

Comment: @Joshua  Benabou I was not clear --- see my edit